# htaccess redirect https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, url-rewriting

I am running a website based upon a CMS. Within the CMS backend there is an option to make the site served via https. This then updates a config.php file. This may or may not be relevant to the question below.

I've posted some questions on Stack Overflow recently about how to redirect to a canonical name. As I am using SSL so there are 4 variants of the same address:

> https://example.com
>
> https://www.example.com
>
> http://example.com
>
> http://www.example.com

The chosen canonical name is the first variant - non www. https.

I was kindly given a snippet of code for this from some members on Stack Overflow. However, this caused an error "redirect loop". Here is the code that generated this redirect loop:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://example.com/$0 [R,L]
```

I fiddled with this snippet. I don't really know what I'm doing so am surprised to report that it APPEARS to be working. I changed the end of 2nd line of the above to "on".

Now, the following incoming URLs redirect thus:

www.example.com =
https://example.com/ (good)

example.com => example.com but when you navigate to any other page comes up as wanted https://example.com/somepage (kinda good)

https://www.example.com => https://example.com (good)

https://example.com => https://example.com (good)

So 2 questions:

1) Why does my code work?! Should it work? I'm cautiously optimistic but skeptical since I really dont know what I'm doing.

2)The second variant above example.com does not redirect upon landing but does upon navigation to anywhere else in the site. Is there a way to set the htaccess file code so that those who visit example.com are redirected to https://example.com?

Comment: @faa thanks. So I never meant to include the actual domain - so yes that's a typo! So the non "s" versions: www.example.com and example.com appear to redirect, kind of. www.example.com redirects to https ://example.com (good) but example.com does not redirect on landing, but does when navigating to any other page. Can I fix that so that visits to example.com redirect?

Comment: I deleted the comment to correct some typos. With HTTPS on, it is really strange that non https requests are affected by the rule. I would be very skeptical too. Something else should be checked. What about your browser's cache?

Comment: @faa could it be the back end settings? In the back end of the CMS I have "enabled https". This updates the config file from http to https. Could that be the source of the riddle?

Comment: I had another typo in my last comment: *non-www http* is meant to be *non-https*.  I don't think so, unless it is a dynamic update. What's the CMS?

Comment: @faa the CMS I'm using is called Ushahidi http://ushahidi.com/products/ushahidi-platform

Comment: Didn't know it. Tried to get some info but couldn't find anything at the link in you comment. I guess you should get all the information about the way it handles http requests. It says "...give you rich information *mapping tools*". Might have a .htaccess file somewhere too. If it does, any custom rule should take into account the CMS rule-set to avoid conflicts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28208/discussion-between-doug-firr-and-faa)